# While using property type for creating descriptor I am getting recursion error

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def fget(self):
        print("Getting ")
        return self.age

    def fset(self, value):
        print("Setting ")
        self.age = value

    def fdel(self):
        print("Deleting")
        del self.age

    age = property(fget, fset, fdel, "I'm the property.")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = Person("ankit", 29)
```

I am trying to use the `property` constructor to create a descriptor. I don't want to use the decorator form of `property`. I am getting error that says

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `object.__setattr__()` finds a binding descriptor (a descriptor with the `__set__` method), it invokes it instead of setting the name:value pair in the instance's `__dict__` - which is very obviously what's expected actually xD.

So in your case, when you instanciate `Person`:

```
Person("ankit", 29)
```

Python calls the initializer:

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

which calls `Person.age.__set__(self, age)`, which calls `fset(self, value)`:

```
def fset(self, value):
    print("Setting ")
    self.age = value
```

which calls `Person.age.__set__(self, age)`, which calls `fset(self, value)`:

```
def fset(self, value):
    print("Setting ")
    self.age = value
```

which calls `Person.age.__set__(self, age)`, which calls `fset(self, value)`:

```
def fset(self, value):
    print("Setting ")
    self.age = value
```

which calls `Person.age.__set__(self, age)`, which calls `fset(self, value)`:

```
def fset(self, value):
    print("Setting ")
    self.age = value
```

which calls `Person.age.__set__(self, age)`, which calls `fset(self, value)`:

```
def fset(self, value):
    print("Setting ")
    self.age = value
```

etc etc etc etc...

IOW you cannot use the same name for the `property` and the underlying instance attribute, since the `property` will completely hide the instance attribute.

Canonically, one uses an implementation attribute with the same name as the `property` just prefixed by a single leading underscore (Python's convention for "protected attribute"):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def fget(self):
        print("Getting ")
        return self._age

    def fset(self, value):
        print("Setting ")
        self._age = value

    def fdel(self):
        print("Deleting")
        del self._age

    age = property(fget, fset, fdel, "I'm the property.")
```

Comment: I like how the answers keep going deeper and deeper into the gritty details as new ones are posted. Very much +1. I expect to see one that goes into the CPython implementation details next :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not going to dig that further, sorry ;-)

Comment: This is a much more detailed answer then my one.. +1 and best practice...

Answer (score 2):

The code in a method is converted into a code object when the file is imported, but not executed until you actually call the method. By the time you run `__init__`, `age` is already the name of your property. Therefore, the line `self.age = age` attempts to call `fset`, as it should. But then `fset` attempts to do `self.age = value`, which just calls `fset` again, etc.

The issue is that you don't have a visible attribute called `age` in your instance, only a descriptor in the class. There are two common solutions to this problem.

1. The one I *see* most frequently is to add an attribute called `_age` to `self`. While there is no privacy in Python, the leading underscore politely asks users not to mess with it unless they want unexpected results.

   In this case your class would look like this:

   ```
   class Person:
       def __init__(self, name, age):
           self.name = name
           self._age = age

       def fget(self):
           print("Getting ")
           return self._age

       def fset(self, value):
           print("Setting ")
           self._age = value

       def fdel(self):
           print("Deleting")
           del self._age

       age = property(fget, fset, fdel, "I'm the property.")
   ```
2. My personal favorite way of doing the same thing is to actually use the fact that the property descriptor shadows the instance attribute. Remember that the shadowing only happens when you use `.` notation (or call `__getattr__` directly). You can still assign to `self.__dict__` just fine. That makes it possible to hold instance-specific data in a way that is not easily visible or accessible, without adding any names to your object's namespace:

   In this case your class would look like this:

   ```
   class Person:
       def __init__(self, name, age):
           self.name = name
           self.__dict__['age'] = age

       def fget(self):
           print("Getting ")
           return self.__dict__['age']

       def fset(self, value):
           print("Setting ")
           self.__dict__['age'] = value

       def fdel(self):
           print("Deleting")
           del self.__dict__['age']

       age = property(fget, fset, fdel, "I'm the property.")
   ```

Comment: I'd personnaly not consider using this "feature" of attribute resolution to hide attributes values as a "best practice", quite on the contrary - actually if I were to stumble upon such code I'd immediatly proceed to refactor it to the canonical `_age` implementation attribute scheme. Maintining code is difficult enough already to not have to waste time with "clever" tricks that add no value  and only make the code non-obvious  (and I've been guilty of quite a few such "clever tricks" myself - lesson learned: do not try to be smart). (NB: @mad-physicist please take no offense ;-) )

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. Certainly none taken.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the name of your `property` var...

The error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

This is because you called the `property` = `age` so the recursion happened on `fset`

Here is an example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def fget(self):
        print("Getting ")
        return self.age

    def fset(self, value):
        print("Setting ")
        self.age = value

    def fdel(self):
        print("Deleting")
        del self.age

    my_age = property(fget, fset, fdel, "I'm the property.")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = Person("ankit", 29)
    print(p.my_age)
```

This will print:

> Getting
>
> 29